# Deploying AppFuse app on cloudbees

Tags: appfuse

I have searched a lot for this but have not found any documentation or blog post on how to deploy Appfuse app on cloudbees. I am kind of new to all this. Does anyone have any documentation or blog describing step by step about how to deploy Appfuse app on cloudbees?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a tutorial on deploying a WAR that was developed with Maven, that should work for AppFuse.

Comment: Why am I getting following errors while deploying locally as well as on cloudbees. It was working fine on cloudbees.SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.my.webapp.listener.StartupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: for com.my.webapp.listener.StartupListenerSEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.my.webapp.listener.UserCounterListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.webapp.listener.UserCounterListenerSEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.my.webapp.jsp.EscapeXmlELResolverListener

Comment: When I deploy the app on cloudbees as war file I get lots of errors :::: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.my.model.User ------------------at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.my.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.my.dao.......And many more errors